# Spring security is blocking Vue.js pages | receiving 403 error

Tags: spring, vue.js, tomcat, spring-security, jwt

I have a Spring/Vuejs project that couples the frontend and backend into one warFile and for some reason the Spring Security setup I have blocks the Vue.js pages when I run the warFile.

When I have the Configuration set this way, it blocks the pages -

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
    security.csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate", "/api/v1/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    security.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I have it set up this way, it shows the pages AND the data from my api's (it creates the JWT but still allows the api calls without Authorization) -

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
    security.csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate", "/api/v1/register", "/**","/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    security.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I have it setup the first way and run the frontend and backend on different ports, it works perfectly. It shows the pages and blocks all API calls that don't have an authorized JWT.

I want the same type of result with backend/frontend in the same warFile

Is there a solution for this???

Comment: please post your full debug logs, and also spring security already has a built in JWTFilter and has had full JWT support since 2018, so please remove the jwtfilter and implement it in accordance to the spring security reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I have it setup the first way and run the frontend and backend on different ports, it works perfectly.

I wonder if this is due to the CORS policy being invoked. Otherwise, Spring Security doesn't take the port number into consideration when making authorization decisions.

> When I have the Configuration set this way, it blocks the pages -

That's because you have this line:

```java
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

It means that any URL, including JS files, will require authentication.

> When I have it set up this way, it shows the pages AND the data from my api's

That's because you have this line:

```java
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

It means that any URL is permitted.

The DSL processes URLs [in the order the paths are declared](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html). I think you want a hybrid of the two. Something like this:

```java
.antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate", "/api/v1/register", "/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

This means that the two `/api` endpoints all `/css` endpoints and all `/js` endpoints won't require authentication, but everything else will.

Consider making the `permitAll` as narrow as you can -- it's not clear to me whether you really want all your JS files to not require authentication.

Comment: I tried what you have here and It blocked the pages in the warFile. I only want those 2 api endpoints there to be open to the public, with the rest requiring authentication. And I want all my Vue.js views (in the warFile) to be public (I will deal with any viewing permissions on the frontend)

It's strange, what you have here should work

Comment: The other thing that trips folks up in war files at times is a context path. Are you deploying to some context other than ROOT? Otherwise, please turn on TRACE logging for org.springframework.security and show the logs for one of the JS requests that's denied.

Comment: No. The root ( localhost:8080/#/ ) is the URL that should be the first thing you see when you open the project up

Comment: @HelpTheNoob Do you have any files in your root path `/`? If you haven't you can just remove `/**`. If you have, you should move it to a sub patt and then remove `/**`.

Comment: @jzheaux You posted this right when I found it. I'm checking it for showing me the way. Thanks!

Comment: I think it was @dur who put it over the finish line, but I'm glad I was able to assist as well!

Answer (score 0):

@jzheaux your root comment led me to the answer.

This was the change I made and it works just as I need it to now. Thanks for the guidance!

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
    security.csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate","/api/v1/register","/static/**","/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    security.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```